# Inserting a table of variable length in the middle of a spreadsheet - how to make spreadsheet dynamically adjust

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula

I am building a  spreadsheet where I want to include a table of transactions (Table 1) based on the month that they occurred. Right now I am using the filter() function to import the relevant transactions by filtering on the date column.

My problem is that I want to add another table right under it in the same spreadsheet, but as the number of transactions vary from month to month, I am not sure where the next Table should start. Ideally, I would like to know a way to start the next table at X rows below the last row of the previous table.

Are there any functions that I can use to ensure that I start the next Table without cutting off Table 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put it into an array like:

```
={FILTER(); FILTER()}
```

note that both filter formula outputs need to have same amount of columns otherwise you will get array literal error

to insert an empty row between them you can do:

```
={FILTER(A:C, A:A<>""); {"", "", ""}; FILTER(F:H, F:F<>"")}
```

---

### UPDATE:

```
={FILTER(A2:C, A2:A > EOMONTH(TODAY(), -2)+1); {"","",""}; 
  FILTER(A2:C, A2:A > EOMONTH(TODAY(), -1)+1)}
```

[image: 0]

Comment: This doesn't seem to work when the results of the filter functions have different numbers of rows. I get the following error message: 
Function ARRAY_ROW parameter 2 has mismatched row size. Expected: 6. Actual: 21.

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: Sure! Here is an example sheet I made for this problem: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18B2RKUHzuA0IlpADojObkgmACc6ffHh8AEBPYIuw4as/edit?usp=sharing